# Separate table/matrix for separate value of variable in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame

```
   Id Name Price sales Profit Month Category Mode Supplier
1   1    A     2     5      8     1        X    K     John
2   1    A     2     6      9     2        X    K     John
3   1    A     2     5      8     3        X    K     John
4   2    B     2     4      6     1        X    L      Sam
5   2    B     2     3      4     2        X    L      Sam
6   2    B     2     5      7     3        X    L      Sam
7   3    C     2     5     11     1        X    M     John
8   3    C     2     5     11     2        X    L     John
9   3    C     2     5     11     3        X    K     John
10  4    D     2     8     10     1        Y    M     John
11  4    D     2     8     10     2        Y    K     John
12  4    D     2     5      7     3        Y    K     John
13  5    E     2     5      9     1        Y    M      Sam
14  5    E     2     5      9     2        Y    L      Sam
15  5    E     2     5      9     3        Y    M      Sam
16  6    F     2     4      7     1        Z    M     Kyle
17  6    F     2     5      8     2        Z    L     Kyle
18  6    F     2     5      8     3        Z    M     Kyle
```

I want to use `xtabs`, `tapply`, `table` or any other function which will give me table for each different category `X,Y,Z` ( so 3 tables) separately. Each table will be supplier vs Mode (i.e for each supplier how many different products were present there)
It will look somewhat like this.

```
Category X

            Mode
    Supplier      K      L      M
       John       4      1      1
       Sam        0      3      0
       Kyle       0      0      0    

Category Y

            Mode
    Supplier      K      L      M
       John       2      0      1
       Sam        0      1      2
       Kyle       0      0      0   


Category Z
```

and so on.

```
table(df$Supplier,df$Mode)
```

gives number of times a supplier has been used under which mode but it doesn't gives 3 tables, it combines all together. So what I can do to have 3 separate tables instead of just one combined?

Comment: This too probably `lapply(split(df[c("Mode","Supplier")], df$Category), table)`, but a simple table is better I guess.

Comment: @DavidArenburg is there any way to now show those rows in output which have all values of zero?

Comment: Maybe `lapply(split(df, df$Category), function(x) table(as.character(x$Supplier), x$Mode))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg it worked perfect. can i have other function other than count in this case? for example if i wanna find the sum or mean of Profit instead of number of suppliers.

Comment: Yes, just insert whatever function you like inside `function` and specify the variable names you want to operate on. For example, `lapply(split(df, df$Category), function(x) tapply(x$Profit, x$Mode, FUN = sum))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg something like lapply(split(df, df$Category), function(x, mean) table(as.character(x$Supplier), x$Mode))? where to specify the variable Profit?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do but I think this is outside of the scope of both this question and the comments section

Answer (score 5):

With table, you could do:

```
with(df,table(Supplier,Mode,Category))
```

output

```
, , Category = X

        Mode
Supplier K L M
    John 4 1 1
    Kyle 0 0 0
    Sam  0 3 0

, , Category = Y

        Mode
Supplier K L M
    John 2 0 1
    Kyle 0 0 0
    Sam  0 1 2

, , Category = Z

        Mode
Supplier K L M
    John 0 0 0
    Kyle 0 1 2
    Sam  0 0 0
```

Comment: worked nice. But is there any way i can remove the rows which are all zero? for example for category X, Kyle row. for category Z, john and sam row.

Comment: @Jaykhan that is more tricky... I think DavidArenburg's solution is better to filter rows